# Linux command line: id, group and getent group not returning the same results

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, chmod, rights

I'm wondering why I get different results from `id` and `group` on one hand, and `getent group` on the other. Steps to reproduce:

```
$ sudo usermod -a -G libvirt eric
$ groups
eric adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare
$ id
uid=1000(eric) gid=1000(eric) groups=1000(eric),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),119(lpadmin),128(sambashare)
$ getent group | grep libvirt
libvirt:x:136:eric
libvirt-qemu:x:64055:libvirt-qemu
libvirt-dnsmasq:x:137:
```

The user eric is clearly a member of `libvirt`. Why doesn't this show up with `id` and `group`? Thanks.

System: Ubuntu Budgie 18.04 4.15.0-34-generic

Comment: If I remember correctly, you'd need to either log out and back in or run `newgrp libvirt` to make the new group ownership effective.

Comment: Yup @Robert. Both works. Thx. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you'd need to either log out and back in or run `newgrp libvirt` to make the new group ownership effective.